# Why does calling a generic local function with a dynamic parameter produce a BadImageFormatException?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, c#-7.0

Playing around with C# 7's Local Functions, I ended up with some interesting behavior. Consider the following program:

```
public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered Main");
    DoSomething("");
}

private void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered DoSomething");
    Generic((dynamic)obj);
    GenericLocal(obj);
    GenericLocal((dynamic)obj); // This breaks the program

    void GenericLocal<T>(T val) => Console.WriteLine("GenericLocal");
}

private void Generic<T>(T val) => Console.WriteLine("Generic");
```

This produces:

> Entered Main

... and then throws a `BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`. Stack trace:

```
   at UserQuery.DoSomething(Object obj)
   at UserQuery.Main()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

(I'm running this in LINQPad, but I get similar results from dotnetfiddle.)

Removing the indicated line in the code yields the output you'd expect:

> Entered Main
>   Entered DoSomething
>   Generic
>   GenericLocal

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: To me, this looks like a bug somewhere in the .NET/C# toolchain.

Comment: sounds like a bug.. this exception isn't even relevant to this situation. If something was very wrong, I'd expect invalidprogramexception not badimageformat (which is more about x86/x64/ia64 mismatch, damaged assembly, etc)

Comment: I think you already know you've caught a bug.

Comment: Mono had the same bug, the same exception with message "Method with open type while not compiling gshared"

Comment: Also happens on the interactive compiler (csi.exe). You should open an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21317). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [turned out to be a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21317), but when the dotnet team looked into it they realized they can't easily fix things so local generic methods would work the way that non-local generic methods would. So instead [they opted](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/21450) to make the compiler produce an error when you try to do this.

> CS8322 Cannot pass argument with dynamic type to generic local function 'GenericLocal' with inferred type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When you help the compiler a little the code will not break:

```
GenericLocal<dynamic>((dynamic)obj); // This doesn't break the program
```

Comment: That is true. However, it runs counter to the purpose of the `(dynamic)` cast.   When I call `Generic((dynamic)obj)`, then the generic type `T` is `string` (because that's what is underlying the object at run-time). Calling `GenericLocal<dynamic>((dynamic)obj)` sticks the generic type as `object`, which is no different than calling `GenericLocal(obj)`.

Comment: This is not a solution when there are constraints on the generic argument. If `GenericLocal` was defined as `void GenericLocal<T>(T arg) where T : Exception` this will fail to compile.